# get the last number of index in array [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

How can I get the last index number in an array?

```
var narr= new Array("test1","test2");
```

I want to print `test2` index number.

Comment: `console.log(narr.length-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `narr[narr.length-1]`

get last item

> `narr.length-1`

last index

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastIndexNumber = narr.length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

index number for last item = `narr.length-1`

Answer (score 0):

Using length property of array, you can get that

```js
var narr= new Array("test1","test2");
var lElementIndex = narr.length -1, lElement = narr[lElementIndex];

console.log('Last Element -' , lElement)
console.log('Last Element Index - ' , lElementIndex)
```